# Grails Hibernate Create hanging forever

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on a Grails application using Hibernate (GORM) and I have one particular domain that is causing me problems which is below. The problem is that when I want to create a new instance of 'TemplateInputTransDisplayMap' I naturally load up the application on the local server and navigate to and click the 'New TemplateInputTransDisplayMap' button but this causes the page to hang. I left it hanging over night and it eventually timed out after 6 hours due to the WIFI going down. How can I find out what the problem is when the page hangs forever thus never producing an error?

```
class TemplateInputTransDisplayMap {

static belongsTo = [templateInput:TemplateInput, templateStep:TemplateStep]
TemplateInput templateInput

Long id
String tsStep
String tiParameterName 
String displayLabel
String defaultValue
String tiMapParameter
String sqlQuery
String selectClause
String whereClause
Long fetchCount
String transTable
String columnName
String displayed
String delimeter
String valueProc
String uiDisplay
String uiSql
String xPath
String isNameValue
String label

static mapping = {

    table 'TI_TRANS_DISP_MAP'
    version false

    id column: 'TI_SYSID', generator: 'foreign', params: [property: 'templateInput']

    templateInput column: 'TI_SYSID', insertable: false, updateable: false
    templateStep column: 'TI_TS_SYSID'
    tsStep column: 'TS_STEP'
    tiParameterName column: 'TI_PARAM_NAME'
    displayLabel column: 'DISPLAY_LABEL'
    defaultValue column: 'DEFAULT_VALUE'
    tiMapParameter column: 'TI_MAP_PARAM'
    sqlQuery column: 'SQL_QUERY'
    selectClause column: 'SELECT_CLAUSE'
    whereClause column: 'WHERE_CLAUSE'
    fetchCount column: 'FETCH_COUNT'
    transTable column: 'TRANS_TABLE'
    columnName column: 'COLUMN_NAME'
    valueProc column: 'VALUE_PROC'
    uiDisplay column: 'UI_DISPLAY'
    uiSql column: 'UI_SQL'
    xPath column: 'XPATH'
    isNameValue column: 'IS_NAME_VALUE'

}

static constraints = {
    tsStep(maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    tiParameterName(maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    displayLabel(maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    defaultValue(maxSize:1500, blank:true, nullable:true)
    tiMapParameter(maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    sqlQuery(maxSize:1500, blank:true, nullable:true)
    selectClause(maxSize:100, blank:true, nullable:true)
    whereClause(maxSize:1000, blank:true, nullable:true)
    fetchCount(maxSize:3, blank:true, nullable:true)
    transTable(maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    columnName(maxSize:30, blank:true, nullable:true)
    displayed(maxSize:1, blank:true, nullable:true)
    delimeter(maxSize:30, blank:true, nullable:true)
    valueProc(maxSize:500, blank:true, nullable:true)
    uiDisplay(maxSize:10, blank:true, nullable:true)
    uiSql(maxSize:900, blank:true, nullable:true)
    xPath(maxSize:2000, blank:true, nullable:true)
    isNameValue(maxSize:3, blank:true, nullable:true)
    label(maxSize:100, blank:true, nullable:true)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a threaddump of your application to find out what's going on.

On unixes, you can simply send a SIGQUIT (3) signal to the java process that runs your application.

```
kill -3 process_id_of_grails_jvm
```

The threaddump goes to stdout, which is catalina.out in Tomcat by default.

There is also the jstack command in the JDK to do a threaddump. You can get the list of accessible java processes with the jps command.